# How to use Play Frame work Iterating?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I try to do a PlayFramework tutorial , but i fail.

**index.scala.html:**

```
Compilation error

not found: type Customer

In C:\test\app\views\index.scala.html at line 2.


@main("welcome") {
@(customer: Customer, orders: List[Order]) 

<h1>Welcome @customer.name!</h1>

<ul> 
@for(order <- orders) {
<li>@order.getTitle()</li>

} 
</ul>
}
```

**Application.java:**

```
public static Result index() {

response().setContentType("text/html");
return ok();

}
```

Please answer.Too many googling but i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to import the model. Try adding this before the `@main` thing:

```
@import your.package.Customer
@import your.another.package.Order
```

Or you may import the entire package like this:

```
@import your.package._
```

***Edit:*** and yes, I suppose this line `@(customer: Customer, orders: List[Order])` should be the first line in your view, not after the `@main` line, so it probably should look like this:

```
@(customer: Customer, orders: List[Order]) 

@import your.package._

@main("welcome") {

    <h1>Welcome @customer.name!</h1>

    <ul> 
      @for(order <- orders) {
        <li>@order.getTitle()</li>
      } 
    </ul>
}
```

In your ***Application.java*** you need to pass the `customer` and `orders` parameters into the view:

```
 public static Result index() {

   response().setContentType("text/html");
   return ok(index.render(SomeService.instance().getCustomer(), SomeAnotherService.instance().getOrders()));
 }
```

***EDIT 2***: Ok, here's how you may do it.

Customer and Order classes may be in the same package, imports inside templates work exactly the same as simple java\scala imports.

Example:

***Customer.java***

```
package models;

public class Customer {
    public String name; //as you use @customer.name thing, the field should be public
}
```

***Order.java***

```
package models;

public class Order {
    private String title; //we can make it private because you use the getter in the template

    public String getTitle() {
         return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
         this.title = title;
    }
}
```

***Application.java***

```
 import models.*;
 import static java.utils.Arrays.*;

 ....

 public static Result index() {

    response().setContentType("text/html");
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.name = "serejja";
    Order order1 = new Order();
    order1.setTitle("my order 1");
    Order order2 = new Order();
    order2.setTitle("my order 2");
    java.util.List orders = asList(order1, order2);
    return ok(index.render(customer, orders));
 }
```

***index.scala.html***

```
@(customer: Customer, orders: List[Order]) 

@import models._

@main("welcome") {

    <h1>Welcome @customer.name!</h1>

    <ul> 
      @for(order <- orders) {
        <li>@order.getTitle()</li>
      } 
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: thank you @serejja. need i custmor and order package? don't search in PlayFramework documentation .please check this [link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaTemplates). I'm not still resolve this problem.

Comment: could you please show to me another simple Iterating example ? i really need it.. too vary hard. i hope you're smart hands.

Comment: Really thank you. You are certainly gentle guy. I bless you. Have a good time.

Comment: i'm so sorry. i try you're updated source. but print compile error. // index.scala.html : @main("welcome") { : missing arguments for method apply in object main; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function // help me serejja T.T

Comment: Can you show your main.scala.html and index.scala.html sources?

Comment: oh my god. finally, I passed this problem. just typographical error. I LOVE YOU! ! ! !